# Dijkstra: Find Shortest path in directed graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dijkstra

Consider the directed graph shown in the figure below. There are multiple shortest paths between vertices S and T. Which one will be reported by Dijstra?s shortest path algorithm? Assume that, in any iteration, the shortest path to a vertex v is updated only when a strictly shorter path to v is discovered.
[image]

My Answer is  SBDT but in solutions it is giving SACET I am not able figure out why..

Comment: Both paths are of length 10 so they are both shortest paths.

Comment: Is this homework? Try to manually run the dijstra algorithm yourself and you will see that it will surely go SACET first and will not replace it with SBDT when able because it is not a better solution, afaik dijstra first checks the edges with the lowest weight

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum : at first :  S = 0 and all adjacent to s will have  weight {a=4, b=3, d=4} so which one is minimum here so go for B isn't it...Extract minimum from queue....Correct me If I am wrong

Comment: This appears to be homework, but remember that the homework tag is obsolete and being retired.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: This depends on the concrete implementation. The Dijkstra algorithm is often implemented using a heap-based priority queue. The order of objects on a heap can be different for the same sequence of insertions depending on the implementation. In other words, you would have to provide the exact algorithm to which your question refers.

Answer (score 4):

Dijkstra's Algorithm picks nodes as follows:

```
B(3) from S
A(4) from S
C(5) from A
E(6) from C
D(7) from S or B
G(8) from E
T(10) from D or E
```

Thus the shortest path to `T` is `SBDT`, `SDT` or `SACET`.

But because of *`"the shortest path to a vertex v is updated only when a strictly shorter path to v is discovered"`*, when `E` is visited, `T`'s prior node for the shortest path will be set as `E` and not changed again.

Thus the answer is `SACET`.

Answer (score -2):

Run it in http://dracos.co.uk/maths/dijkstra/
Answer is SDT.
Reason:
After node S, its immediate neighbors are considered
ie:A(4),D(7),B(3)
Now immediate neighbors of these nodes are considered. We arrive at SDT(10) before node C is considered because C is not the immediate neighbor of S.
Answer: SDT